# Do you use あります or います when talking about a sports team?

Tags: grammar

I know you use いる to talk about living things, but is a team separate from its players enough to refer to it as a non-living thing?

Comment: I suggest you to add some example sentences or guesses to your question

Answer (score 3):

Both 「いる」 and 「ある」 can be used correctly ***but not interchangeably*** so.  Only one of the two will be correct for a given context /situation.

Only 「いる」 is correct when saying that a team is physically at a place at a given time.  For instance, you occasionally get to see an entire team at an airport, train station, hotel, etc.

「昨日{きのう}ヒルトンホテルに行ったら、ロビーにNYヤンキースが**いた**。」← You cannot use 「あった」 in this sentence.

Only 「ある」 is correct when saying, for example, that a certain city has a pro-baseball team or the like.

「この町｛まち｝には、プロ野球｛やきゅう｝チームは**ある**が、プロサッカーチームはない。」← You can never use 「いる」 in this sentence.

Comment: So when talking about the team members (people) you use いる; when it is about an abstract entity, it's ある?